# How to cut from a polygon and merge with another polygon automatically in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon

I have 2 different polygon layers as shown below. [image]

I want to cut from polygon #2 and merge that piece (#3) with polygon #1 as shown in the second picture.
[image]

This is part of a model and I can't edit it manually. The solution must be a function/tool included into the QGIS Graphical Modeler.

Comment: So you want to extend polygon 1 so it covers polygon 2, then clip? Or should polygon1 already be longer so it covers 2 in your screenshots (/ the screenshots arent correct)? It is unclear for me the "rules" how to create polygon 3

Comment: I’ve tried the “snap geometries to layer” tool. In this case it would resolve the problem, but in a other cases it might snap unnecessary polygons. I’ll upload an example. 
Yes, I want to extend polygon 1 by merging polygon 3 to it. I don’t know how polygon 3 can be created. 
Apologies if I wasn’t clear enough.